# docker-compose: unable to execute commands from the yaml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to execute a wait-for-it.sh script in my docker-compose.yaml file using "command:".  I also tried to even execute the ls command as well.  They both resulted in command not found.  Howeer, if I go to the command line, I am able to run both commands.

Here is the docker-compose.yaml file:

```
  rabbitmq:
     container_name: "myapp_rabbitmq"
     tty: true
     image: rabbitmq:management
     ports:
       - 15672:15672
       - 15671:15671
       - 5672:5672
     volumes:
       - /rabbitmq/lib:/var/lib/rabbitmq
       - /rabbitmq/log:/var/log/rabbitmq
       - /rabbitmq/conf:/etc/rabbitmq/
  service1:
     container_name: "service1"
     build:
       context: .
       dockerfile: ./service1.dockerfile
     links:
       - mongo
       - rabbitmq
     depends_on:
       - mongo
       - rabbitmq
     command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "rabbitmq:5672", "-t", "90"]
  service2:
     container_name: "service2"
     build:
       context: .
       dockerfile: ./service2.dockerfile
     links:
       - mongo
       - rabbitmq
     depends_on:
       - mongo
       - rabbitmq
     command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "rabbitmq:5672", "-t", "90"]
```

What could be causing this as the commands work from the command line, just not from docker-compose file?  I am using "docker-compose up -d" to start the containers, if that helps any.

Comment: Not sure what your directory looks like, but you reference `./service1.dockerfile` and `./service2/dockerfile` which seems odd, having one dockerfile in a path and one as a file with a `.docker` extension.

Comment: That was a typo.  The slash should have been a dot.

Comment: A v1 compose file is deprecated as are links, please consider updating to at least v2 and use networks instead of links. What command are you running that's successful? It's not clear that you are running it in a container built from the same image.

Comment: I mean if I run from the terminal console, the commands work.

Comment: You need to mount the /wait-for-it.sh script to a container using volumes first.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a sample docker-compose.yml file that uses the approach you specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `wait-for-it.sh` is not found at runtime, then I suspect that the `wait-for-it.sh` is not inside your docker image.

You can add this file to the image using the [ADD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) instruction in your Dockerfile(s)

`ADD wait-for-it.sh /wait-for-it.sh`